# How to use Adapt.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to use Adapt.js?
Can you give me some demo samples with adapt.js?
For example, after I get adapt.js into index.html Then in `<body>` tag I try some lines such as:

```
<div class="container_12">
    <div class="grid_4">Hello</div> 
    <div class="grid_8">12345</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Why "12345" string breaks new line. It must be next to "Hello" string?

My CSS file:

```
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.alpha,
.omega {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.align_center,
.align_right {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: what css are you working with ? also please share your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [site doc](http://adapt.960.gs/)

1) create CSS files for necessary widths

2) set range array

```
var ADAPT_CONFIG = {

  path: 'assets/css/',
  dynamic: true,
  range: [
    '0px    to 760px  = mobile.css',
    '760px  to 980px  = 720.css',
    '980px  to 1280px = 960.css',
    '1280px to 1600px = 1200.css',
    '1600px to 1920px = 1560.css',
    '1940px to 2540px = 1920.css',
    '2540px           = 2520.css'
  ]
};
```